# Symbol’s value as variable is void: Info-default-directory-list

Tags: init-file, start-up

I am getting this error when I start my `emacs`. It happens even if I comment out my `init.el` but not when I use the `--no-init-file` option.

Any thoughts on how to debug this issue? If this is a an upstream issue, do I need to create a Ticket for that?

Comment: Bisect your init file to find out what is interfering.

Comment: @Drew, Commenting out the entire `init.el` using `;` was still causing this issue. Is there anything else in the `emacs.d` that could be causing this?

Comment: Presumably `--no-init-file` just prevents using your init file - any init file you might have somewhere. I don't know why that would be different from having only a commented-out init file. Check whether you might have some other init file, i.e., with one of the other acceptable names. See the Emacs manual, node [Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Comment: @Nishant FWIW, it's happening to me too. Which Emacs version are you using?

Comment: @ManuelUberti 27.0.50, I guess I build it from source to have support for `lucid`. How about you?

Comment: @Nishant same, built from sources: GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-debian-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2018-02-24

Comment: It could be a bug related to the recent [`eary-init.el` changes](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=24acb31c04b4048b85311d794e600ecd7ce60d3b).

Comment: @npostavs Create a ticket upstream?

Comment: I've already reported this on the relevant `emacs-devel` thread: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-02/msg00532.html. A workaround for now is to set `package-enable-at-startup` to `nil` in your `early-init-file`.

Comment: @Basil I don't have an early-init-file :-) Only init.el like most users!

Comment: @Nishant I didn't either, but the aforementioned commit, which is causing the `Info-default-directory-list` errors, introduces one such `early-init-file`, and setting `package-enable-at-startup` to `nil` in this new `early-init-file` is a workaround for the errors for now, if not for the foreseeable future. See `(emacs) Early Init File` and the `emacs-devel` thread I linked.

Comment: Of course, your other option is to use the latest **stable** version of Emacs, which is 26.

Comment: @Basil the latest stable version is 25. 
emacs26 is still in RC

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan I know, I was future-proofing my comment. :) I meant that 26 is the latest stable version relative to the latest development snapshot, which is 27.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed in [commit 2db57579b0 of 2018-03-19](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=2db57579b08ac99c464b6d3698648b3167fc5d55) by initialising `Info-default-directory-list` et al. before loading `early-init-file`.

Now, `package-initialize` will either be called automatically after loading `early-init-file` and before loading `user-init-file`, or you can manually call it in `user-init-file`. In the latter case, you should set `package-enable-at-startup` to `nil` in `early-init-file` so as to avoid giving rise to the "Unnecessary call to `package-initialize` in init file" warning.